# if else with missing observations in R

Tags: r, if-statement, missing-data

Lets say I have following 2 variables

```
z1=c(0,1,1,0,NA,1,0,NA ,1)
z2=c(0,1,0,NA,1,0,0,0,NA)
```

So the both variables has missing values. I need to create a new variable Z as follows,

Z=1 if at least one of the variables (z1 and z2) are equal to 1.(following situations z1=1 & z2=1 , z1=0 & z2=1 ,z1=1 & z2=0 , z1=1 & z2=NA , z1=NA & z2=1)

Z=0 if at least one of the variables(z1 and z2) are equal to 0.(following situations z1=0 & z2=0 , z1=0 & z2=NA ,z1=NA & z2=0 )

So i performed the following nested ifelse statement and got this output,

```
     ifelse(z1==1|z2==1,1,ifelse((z1==0|z2==0),0 ,0))
  0  1  1 NA  1  1  0 NA  1
```

there seems to be something wrong with my if-else statement as my ideal output should be something like this,

```
0  1  1 0  1  1  0 0  1
```

can any one help me to figure out what is incorrect in my code ?

Thank you

Comment: What if `z1 = 1` while `z2=0`, then what value shall `z` be? They match both conditions, which cause conflict?

Comment: Your condition is not clear as iluminzhao mentioned.  `z= 1` and `z= 0` both have condition of `at least one of the variables`

Comment: Your ifelse doesn't address what to do about NA's . Given that, your ifelse leaves the NA's alone. That is why your code fails.

Comment: @aginensky  Hi i updated the question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We can use `pmax` with `na.rm` as `TRUE`

```
pmax(z1, z2, na.rm = TRUE)
#[1] 0 1 1 0 1 1 0 0 1
```

Comment: Hi Thank you for your answer. But I think that i wont be able to use this if there are more than 2 classes .isnt it ?

Comment: @student_R123 You can use it `pmax(z1, z2. z3..., zn, na.rm = TRUE)`  If you have trouble in writing the `zs`, then `do.call(pmax, c(mget(ls(pattern= "^z\\d+$")), na.rm = TRUE))`

Comment: sorry i meant more than 2 classes. Thank you (ex : if my levels of the variables are like 1,2 and 3)

Comment: @student_R123  In that case, your logic should also be different, right?

Comment: @student_R123  If `z1 <- c(0, 2, 1, 0, NA, 1, 0, NA, 1); z2 <- c(0, 1, 0, NA, 2, 0, 0, 0, NA)`, what would be the output

Answer (score 1):

I believe `coalesce()` in the `dplyr` packages accomplishes your desired output:

```
library(dplyr)

coalesce(z1, z2)
[1] 0 1 1 0 1 1 0 0 1
```

If you are looking to perhaps append the new values to your previous:

```
df <- tibble(
  z1 = c(0, 1, 1, 0, NA, 1, 0, NA, 1),
  z2 = c(0, 1, 0, NA, 1, 0, 0, 0, NA)
)

df %>% 
  mutate(z3 = coalesce(z1, z2))

# A tibble: 9 x 3
     z1    z2    z3
  <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
1     0     0     0
2     1     1     1
3     1     0     1
4     0    NA     0
5    NA     1     1
6     1     0     1
7     0     0     0
8    NA     0     0
9     1    NA     1
```